# Not getting remote user names with (Get-WmiObject -Class win32_computersystem -ComputerName $computer).UserName

Tags: powershell, remote-access, powershell-4.0

First and foremost thanks for your time and help.

My issue here is that I am having an erratic behavior in getting the name of the remote logged users. I want to send a message to a certain list of computers or IPs, and if somebody is logged get who saw the message.
To do so I created a script which should read and get the computer names one by one, and see if is connected. If so, get the name of the user, send the message and then show in table and write on a txt file the results:

```
#We read the "Lista" file with IPs or computer names, works with both
$PCLIST = Get-Content 'C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\Lista.txt'
#Add the date tot he txt files to be created
$Fecha = date 
echo $Fecha > "C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\ListOffline.txt"
echo $Fecha > "C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\Done.txt"

#We check every computer and if ONLINE send the message
foreach ($computer in $PCLIST) 
{
    if ((Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $computer -WarningAction SilentlyContinue).PingSucceeded -eq $true) #If ping back is succesfull then write the message
        {              
            $Usuario = (Get-WmiObject -Class win32_computersystem -ComputerName $computer).UserName
            if ((Get-WmiObject -Class win32_computersystem -ComputerName $computer).UserName) {" "} else {$Usuario = "Usuario Remoto"}

            $output = @{ 'Computer_Name / IP' = $computer }          
            $output.Usuario_Conectado = (Get-WmiObject -Class win32_computersystem -ComputerName $computer).UserName                   

            msg * /server:$computer "Hey!!" $Usuario ", Something meaninfull :) " #Message1
            msg * /server:$computer "And something more meaningfull even ;)" #Message2

            echo "$computer, avisado y recibido por $Usuario" >> "C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\Done.txt"
        }
        else
        {            
            $output = @{'Computer_Name / IP' = $computer }
                        $output.Usuario_Conectado = "OFFLINE" 

            echo $Computer >> "C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\ListOffline.txt"
        }
        [PSCustomObject]$output 
}
```

The message part works as expected and the computers, when logged, can see the messages BUT:

1. I can't get the names of the remote logged users on the computer's list, I get mine and the rest as empty names. In some weird variation I could, but can't find what the problem is anymore. As pre-requisites I allowed Win RM and firewall config:

- I went to the computers where this will be sent and modified the registry: "*reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server" /v "AllowRemoteRPC" /t "REG_DWORD" /d "1" /f*"
- and opened the sshnet to allow remote access to get the names: "*netsh firewall set service remoteadmin enable*"

[image: In orange you see I get empty names on logged remote users]

In the image in the orange circles should go the remote users logged but I get empty names

2. I want to send the message IF the user is logged, as remote user or on the console, now the txt file of "Done" gets written even when the user don't receive any message...

So, there should be an issue on this call: "**(Get-WmiObject -Class win32_computersystem -ComputerName $computer).UserName**" to get the names, this worked but I can't get the names on the remote logged users computers anymore... any idea or suggestion? I can accept get those in other form if is available and easier.

Thanks and best,
Juan

Comment: Have you tested your query manually? ```Get-CimInstance –ComputerName computername –ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object UserName```

Comment: You can test remote user logons using a function developed here - **How to find a logged-in user remotely using PowerShell** <https://4sysops.com/archives/how-to-find-a-logged-in-user-remotely-using-powershell/>

Comment: Why do you repeat `(Get-WmiObject -Class win32_computersystem -ComputerName $computer).UserName` where only once would suffice?

Comment: `Win32_ComputerSystem.UserName` might only get the console-connected user.  Do you get any workable results if you query for the [`Win32_LoggedOnUser` association class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-loggedonuser)?

Comment: thanks @NeoTheNerd, yes I tried manually and outside the script, when is my computer it works and I get the user name but on remote computers I get an empty string... which is weird...

Comment: And thanks, this one: https://4sysops.com/archives/how-to-find-a-logged-in-user-remotely-using-powershell/ I saw it before but as you can see it uses the same call to get the remote user. I even copy and used his function and still empty names for the remote ones... so same error

Comment: @Theo that is right, one time and keep it on variable as RemoteUser should suffice but because I am not getting the name, but I got it at some moment, I keep trying to get it on screen or in the variable... I swear that one time I got the remote logged names, among some errors and so but saw them on screen

Comment: @LanceU.Matthews I tried your option, interestingly same results but in this case even with my local and logged computer, and with my user. I can't see it with your option...

Comment: I guess its back to old school using the  **query** command <https://www.itdroplets.com/get-list-users-logged-list-servers-powershell/> or new school using **Get-RDUserSession** cmdlet <https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/remotedesktop/get-rdusersession?view=windowsserver2016-ps>

Answer (score 0):

If you're using command line utilities anyway, why not use `quser` as its designed to get the information you need:

```
Function FindLogons {
    Param (
        [string]$Computer
    )
    Try {
        $Query = quser /server:$Computer 2>&1
        If ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) {
            $ErrorDetail = $Query.Exception.Message
            Switch -Wildcard ($Query) {
                '*[1722]*' { 
                    $Status = 'Remote RPC not enabled'
                }
                '*[5]*' {
                    $Status = 'Access denied'
                }
                'No User exists for*' {
                    $Status = 'No logged on users found'
                }
                default {
                    $Status = 'Error'
                }
            }
            $result = [pscustomobject]@{ErrorStatus = $Status;ErrorMessage = $ErrorDetail}
            $result.PSObject.Properties | ForEach-Object {
                Write-Host $_.Name "`t" $_.Value
            }
            Return 
        }
        Else {
            Write-Host "Query complete"
        }
        $Query | Select-Object -Skip 1 -ErrorAction Stop | ForEach-Object {
            $CurrentLine = $_.Trim() -Replace '\s+',' ' -Split '\s'
            # If session is disconnected different fields will be selected
            If ($CurrentLine[2] -eq 'Disc') {
                $SearchResult = [pscustomobject]@{
                    UserName = $CurrentLine[0];
                    SessionName = $null;
                    Id = $CurrentLine[1];
                    State = $CurrentLine[2];
                    IdleTime = $CurrentLine[3];
                    LogonTime = $CurrentLine[4..($CurrentLine.GetUpperBound(0))] -join ' '
                }
                # LogonTime = $CurrentLine[4..6] -join ' ';
            }
            Else {
                $SearchResult = [pscustomobject]@{
                    UserName = $CurrentLine[0];
                    SessionName =  $CurrentLine[1];
                    Id = $CurrentLine[2];
                    State = $CurrentLine[3];
                    IdleTime = $CurrentLine[4];
                    LogonTime = $CurrentLine[5..($CurrentLine.GetUpperBound(0))] -join ' '
                }
            }
            If ($SearchResult) {
                $SearchResult
            }
        }
    }
    Catch {
        Write-Host "Error: $_"
    }
    Write-Host "Done"
}
```